# add custom layout into DraggableGridView

Tags: android, viewgroup

I use [DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) to create a ViewGroup, and I want to add my custom view into it. 
Below is my custom layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Green"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the background color of LinearLayout should be green, which is displayed correctly in the ViewGroup.
However, the ImageView and the TextView aren't displayed on the screen, neither even the background color of the TextView.

And this is my code to add the custom view:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.item_name);
textView.setText(contact.getName());
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

gridView.addView(v);
```

What's the problem? Thank you.